# Casting data correctly in R using the grep function

Tags: r

I'm trying to reshape my data based on the value in a particular column (ie. "up" and "down").  The Up and Down are not in the same order in the data frame, so I'm having difficultly "casting" the data into the right shape.

I've tried used the cast function to shift the data, but I can't get the answers to work in a consistent (aka accurate) fashion.

This is my input:

```
input = structure(list(X = 1:6, Report = c("Sales.csv", "Sales.csv", 
"Sales.csv", "Sales.csv", "Sales.csv", "Sales.csv"), Shock = c("Currencies.USD_Up", 
"Currencies.USD_Down", "Currencies.AUD_Up", "Currencies.AUD_Down", 
"Currencies.EUR_Down", "Currencies.EUR_Up"), Result = c(-519375.9816, 
-7388851.423, -42950.77683, -667.367063, -12819532.15, -138054.0061
), FX = c("USD", "USD", "AUD", "AUD", "EUR", "EUR")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

and this is my preferred output:

```
output = structure(list(X = 1:3, Report = c("Sales.csv", "Sales.csv", 
"Sales.csv"), Shock = c("Currencies.USD", "Currencies.AUD", "Currencies.EUR"
), Currency = c("USD", "AUD", "EUR"), Up = c(-519375.9816, -42950.77683, 
-138054.0061), Down = c(-7388851.423, -667.367063, -12819532.15
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Because the EUR data in the input is in a different order, I can't seem to make the data shape correctly.  I've tried using the grep function to order this, but I can't make this work.  Can anyone suggest a better way?

Comment: `library(tidyverse); input %>% select(-X) %>% separate(Shock, into = c("Shock", "Direction"), sep = "_") %>% spread(Direction, Result)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a `tidyverse` approach to do it:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)
input %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  separate(Shock, c("Shock", "tmp"), sep = "_") %>% 
  rename(Currency = FX) %>% 
  select(-X) %>% 
  spread(tmp, Result) %>% 
  mutate(X = row_number()) %>% 
  select(X, Report, Shock, Currency, Up, Down)
```